# How to merge two dictionaries together and link them

Tags: python, dictionary

Im doing an exercise where I have to ask for input of info and input of medical records, and I'm not sure how to "link" a medical record from one dictionary, to a patient of my other dictionary.

So far, I've got this.

For patient info:

```
info_patients = []

while True:
    Name = input("Insert name: ")
    Lastname = input("Insert last name: ")
    Birth = input("Insert date of birth: ")
    Nationality = input("Insert nationality:")
    repeat = input("Do you need to add more data? (yes / no): ")

    info_patients.append({
            "Name": Name,
            "Lastname": Lastname,
            "Birth": Birth,
            "Nationality": Nationality
            
            })

    if repeat == 'no' or repeat == 'NO':
        break
    
print(info_patients)
```

For medical records:

```
med_record = []

while True:
    Date = input("Insert date of treatment: ")
    Reason = input("Insert reason of treatment: ")
    Doctor = input("Insert doctor in charge of treatment: ")
    Remark = input("Insert any remarks:")
    repeat = input("Do you need to add more data? (yes / no): ")

    med_record.append({
            "Date": Date,
            "Reason": Reason,
            "Doctor": Doctor,
            "Remark": Remark
            
            })

    if repeat == 'no' or repeat == 'NO':
        break
    
print(med_record)
```

How can I make it so, by an user input, link a medical record from my last dict to a patient of my first dict?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It would be helpful if you gave an example of what sort of output you're looking for. You should probably pare down your example code to a few concrete entries, and show us what you've tried.  Right now we see how you're constructing two dictionaries, but it's not clear what you are attempting to do to link them - or what precisely you mean by 'link'.

Comment: The medical record dictionaries need to also contain the patient's name, then that to be used to find the info in the `info_patients` list — so the patient's name is the "link" between the two.